# pasteboard ios in javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, hybrid-mobile-app, uipasteboard

Is there any way of using iOS pasteboard concept in javascript?

I am developing hybrid mobile app and my requirement is to store a value in system postcard and retrieve it later even after app is uninstalled.

Please provide solution by javascript/jquery. I am not from iOS background but I found something here stating system pasteboards are persistent. Please refer: [Apple Developer: Copy, Cut, and Paste Operations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/UsingCopy,Cut,andPasteOperations/UsingCopy,Cut,andPasteOperations.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copy to clipboard using Javascript in iOS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045777/copy-to-clipboard-using-javascript-in-ios)

Comment: @david thanks. But I don't want to copy any text, rather I require to store a persistent value in system pasteboard that I can use even after app unistallation.