# Copy Button For Ios Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, iphone, safari, copy-paste

> hi everyone, i want copy button in my mobile website and i have
>   implement it with JS, it works fine for android but on ios text not
>   copying, is there any way to copy textarea text on ios safari ?
>
> this is my code which worked on android browser
>
> ```
> var input  = document.getElementById("input_output");
> var button = document.getElementById("copy-button");
>
> button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
>     event.preventDefault();
>     input.select();
>     document.execCommand("copy");
> });
> ```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045777/copy-to-clipboard-using-javascript-in-ios

Answer (score 3):

You can try this it will work for Ios and other Browsers.

```
button.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
event.preventDefault();
    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/ipad|ipod|iphone/i)) {
            var $input = $('#input_output');
            $input.val();
            var el = $input.get(0);
            var editable = el.contentEditable;
            var readOnly = el.readOnly;
            el.contentEditable = true;
            el.readOnly = false;
            var range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNodeContents(el);
            var sel = window.getSelection();
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
            el.setSelectionRange(0, 999999);
            el.contentEditable = editable;
            el.readOnly = readOnly;

            var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
            $input.blur();
            var msg = successful ? 'successful ' : 'un-successful ';  


        }
        else{

            var copyTextarea = document.querySelector('#input_output');
            copyTextarea.select();

            var successful = document.execCommand('copy');
            var msg = successful ? 'successful ' : 'unsuccessful';

        }
```

});

Comment: Is there a non-jQuery version for this?

Comment: It worked for me, but the virtual keyboard shows up for half a second then it closes. Can't figure how to prevent it from showing.