# Issue with copying text to clipbard from the input (JS, jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, execcommand

I have table, in one of the tds there is hidden input, once i click on that td text from the input should be copied to clipboard.

All works fine on chrome, safari, firefox desktop browsers and android mobile. **But doesn't work on apple mobile.**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('[id^=clickorderno-]').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var copyOrderno = $(this).data('copyid');
    var orderText = $('#copyorderno-' + copyOrderno).select();
    console.log(orderText);
    try {
      var successful1 = document.execCommand('copy');
      var msg1 = successful1 ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';
    } catch (err) {}
  });
});
```

```css
.sample-td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.input-noshow {
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 0px;
  outline: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  width: 5px;
  color: transparent;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td data-copyid='1' id="clickorderno-1" class='sample-td'>
      <input type='text' class='input-noshow' id='copyorderno-1' value='To be copied'>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Any sugestions, thx for your help in advance

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045777/copy-to-clipboard-using-javascript-in-ios

Comment: You cant copy from hidden inputs

Comment: input is hidden with css

Comment: Use `$(this).attr('data-copyid');` instead of `$(this).data('copyid');`