# execCommand to copy text from iOS/android?

Tags: javascript

I've got this 
(I know that  isn't so much correct, but i need to keep it if possible because of css/styles)
    
                                        
on html, and this in my javascript

```
function CopyToClipboard() {
  var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
  copyText.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.getElementById("myInput").value = "Copied to Clipboard!"; 
}
```

tested on iPhone and Android, seems not working...why?

Comment: So how is it called?

Comment: For iOS you you have to do things a bit differently. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045777/copy-to-clipboard-using-javascript-in-ios