# Copy link on button click into clipboard not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently trying to write a JS function to provide a "copy link on button click". It works fine on Android and PC but when I try it on my iPad or iPhone I'm getting an error:

> TypeError: Argument 1 ('refNode') to Range.selectNodeContents must be
>   an instance of Node

I've build in a way to copy it on IOS devices too, because the normal copy command don't works:

```js
function copyUrl(e) {
    var tmp = jQuery("<input>");
    jQuery("body").append(tmp.val(e));

    if (navigator.userAgent.match(/ipad|ipod|iphone/i)) {
        var editable = tmp.contentEditable;
        var readOnly = tmp.readOnly;
        tmp.contentEditable = true;
        tmp.readOnly = false;
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(tmp);
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        sel.removeAllRanges();
        sel.addRange(range);
        tmp.setSelectionRange(0, 999999);
        tmp.contentEditable = editable;
        tmp.readOnly = readOnly;
    } else {
        tmp.select();
    }

    document.execCommand("copy");
    tmp.remove();
    alert("Link copied successfully!")
}
```

```css
div {
  padding: 30px;
}

a {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a:hover {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <a class="btn-floating" onclick="copyUrl('google.de')">Share</a>
</div>
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Worked for me on my Safari.

Comment: @Raymond LOL! Thats so strange. Do you have an iPhone or iPad too?

Comment: I tested with iPad, but it is old and outdated Safari could be an issue for testing. I posted an answer with the documentation on range.

Comment: Another revision, test please to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

> If you pass the JQuery element as an argument element, it will give
>   the TypeError you are getting because it does not interface the Node.

The TypeError message is related to you not doing one of the following.

```
// copy(document.getElementByClass("")[0];
copy(document.getElementById("")); // Pure JS
copy($("#")[0]); // JQuery
```

**Example, as asked for a link passing a variable string:** It creates an element then removes it after selecting it and copying the variable's value we inserted in it.

I suggest looking into the library [Cliboard.js](https://clipboardjs.com/)

```js
function copy(href) {
    var dummy = document.createElement("input");
    document.body.appendChild(dummy);
    dummy.setAttribute('value', href);
    dummy.select();
    document.execCommand("copy");
    document.body.removeChild(dummy);
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="copy('https://wehavehaxedthecliboard.com')">Copy</a>
```

**FROM IOS** [Copy to clipboard using Javascript in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045777/copy-to-clipboard-using-javascript-in-ios)

```js
var copy = function(href) {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    input.setAttribute('value', href);

    var isiOSDevice = navigator.userAgent.match(/ipad|iphone/i);

    if (isiOSDevice) {

        var editable = input.contentEditable;
        var readOnly = input.readOnly;

        input.contentEditable = true;
        input.readOnly = false;

        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNodeContents(input);

        var selection = window.getSelection();
        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);

        input.setSelectionRange(0, 999999);
        input.contentEditable = editable;
        input.readOnly = readOnly;

        document.body.removeChild(input);
    } else {
        input.select();
    }

    document.execCommand('copy');
    document.body.removeChild(input);
}
```

```html
I think this works on ios
<a href="#" onclick="copy('http://google.com')">Copy text</a>
```

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know if it works! Thanks!

Comment: I just redid it. Sorry I had to get to a computer, wasn't able to code before because I was on a Ipad.

Comment: Hm strange, I don't have an element "el"?

Comment: @Mr.Jo this is just a working example on passing the element, if you want me to fix your code give me a second.

Comment: Whats with the IE < 9 ? Do we need this?

Comment: @Mr.Jo no you do not, I removed it for you. It was just to make sure when I wrote it, that the document functions were available. Some browsers do not support certain functions.

Comment: Seems to be not working on my iPad anymore. Cache is cleared. I'm wondering because normally the execCommand("copy") don't works within IOS.

Comment: Seems to be good, but the prevent scrolling on iPad don't works. It runs down to the end of the page which is a bit wired :0.

Comment: Still working but still getting a scrolling on my iPad :/ sorry mate

Comment: Im still looking into it, kind of difficult it seems.

Comment: Oh hey again, this would be nice! I've also tried some unsuccessful things.

Comment: Have you found a hack?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190173/discussion-between-raymond-and-mr-jo).

Comment: Still not found a solution. Maybe I need to accept this. It works fine everywhere but  on my old iPad 2 within Safari is still the scroll to the bottom.

Comment: Hey Raymond, I'll love to check your answer. But maybe you can get a last view onto the iPad issue?

Comment: Note: I covered the scenario where the user denies permission to the clipboard. Additionally, the message "link copied" will be displayed even if the user copies manually.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
 $('.copy-to-clipboard input').click(function() {
 $(this).focus();
 $(this).select();
 document.execCommand('copy');
 alert('Copy to Clipboard!');
    });
});
</script>


<span class="copy-to-clipboard">
 <input id="copy-test" readonly type="text" value="google.de">
</span>
```

Comment: This does not take a variable as a string for the URL, as he asked for it to in his example. And all my example's do cover this. As he stated this does not work in iOS.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one

```js
/*
    Copy text from any appropriate field to the clipboard
  By Craig Buckler, @craigbuckler
  use it, abuse it, do whatever you like with it!
*/
(function() {

    'use strict';
  
  // click events
  document.body.addEventListener('click', copy, true);

    // event handler
    function copy(e) {

    // find target element
    var 
      t = e.target,
      c = t.dataset.copytarget,
      inp = (c ? document.querySelector(c) : null);
      
    // is element selectable?
    if (inp && inp.select) {
      
      // select text
      inp.select();

      try {
        // copy text
        document.execCommand('copy');
        inp.blur();
        
        // copied animation
        t.classList.add('copied');
        setTimeout(function() { t.classList.remove('copied'); }, 1500);
      }
      catch (err) {
        alert('please press Ctrl/Cmd+C to copy');
      }
      
    }
    
    }

})();
```

```css
div {
  padding: 30px;
}

a {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 12px 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

a:hover {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
<input style="position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  right: -150px;
  top: -150px;overflow:hidden;" type="text" id="website" value="http://hpecas.com/teste" />

<a class="btn-floating" href="#" data-copytarget="#website">Share</a>
</div>
```