# The document.execCommand() method is not working on safari in Iphone

Tags: javascript

I'm doing copy text when click on the button to copy the text from the text field. But not working on safari in Iphone
This is my function

```
function myFunction() {
      var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
      copyText.select();
      document.execCommand("copy");
     }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Have you checked the value of each variable using Safari's developer tools?

Comment: A quick search brings up this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045777/copy-to-clipboard-using-javascript-in-ios , seems there may be ios specific issues you need to work around for this.

Answer (score 0):

Copy command works from iOS 10. I think you may not have the supported version.
See here for browsers/iOS support [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)