# Keyboard triggering after executing document.execCommand("copy") in iOS webview mobile device

Tags: javascript, ios, webview

I want to copy a text in iOS mobile webview

The text is being copied but the iOS keyboard is opening up

```
document.getElementById("code").select();
document.execCommand("copy");
```

How to solve this. Help appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Copy to clipboard using Javascript in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045777/copy-to-clipboard-using-javascript-in-ios/46858992#46858992)
This one helped me out mitrooooon.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).