# copy to clipboard on IOS programatically without user interaction javascript

Tags: javascript, ios, copy, clipboard

So I was reading a lot of people saying that you can't copy in IOS without user interaction, but this is not true.

Here is the proof: https://www.latestdeals.co.uk/claim/beauty-pie/beauty-pie-15-off-free-delivery-first-order

If you open this website on an IOS device, you will see that the code copies successfully WITHOUT any user interaction, but HOW this is made?

I tried almost everything on my hand, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: follow this link for the try
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34045777/copy-to-clipboard-using-javascript-in-ios

Comment: @VhoraAbdulrauf all of those answers have `execCommand('copy')`, which needs user interaction

Comment: maybe trying to force any user event, trigger some clicks but i'm not sure

Comment: Hmm.. I went to that link, saw the "Copied Code" message... switched to Notes... Paste does NOT paste that code - it pastes the last text I had copied.

Comment: The lastdeals site relies on `load` event to force you to accept the clipboard permission, which is considered an interaction. https://i.imgur.com/qKGubmj.png