# Is it possible to process a deep link if user has just downloaded the app from the store?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store, deep-linking

Is it possible to process a deep link in next case:

1. User has no app at his phone
2. User downloaded app from AppStore by deep link
3. User launch app

Any ideas?

Comment: You may try to copy link to buffer when it's clicked via JS and get it back on app launch, but this won't work reliably. So you have to use third-party solution for that. Branch.io and Firebase Dynamic Links for example.

Answer (score 4):

There is a type of deeplink called as **"Deferred Deep link"**, what it does is it checks whether app is installed or not, if not then redirect to AppStore and once installed after user log's in, then deeplink redirects the user to that particular view controller.

Refer to this:

[Deferred Deep Linking in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25855618/deferred-deep-linking-in-ios)

https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/bring-users-back-to-your-app-deep-linking-for-ios-5c57d8d85c2d