# Is there a way to get the link from which an app was installed?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am new to app development and I cannot figure a way to get the install url from which the app was downloaded/installed (ex: the ad url with the utm parameters) and read it in the app.
For example if I open an add and the downloads the app from that ad URL, can I read that URL inside the app when he opens the app? I found the getInstallReferer method but I am not sure is the one I need to use and is only valid for Android. I am using React Native

Answer (score 2):

The search term you're looking for is Deferred Deep Linking.
On android [it is supported natively](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library) as you have said. You can use
[play-install-referrer-react-native](https://github.com/uerceg/play-install-referrer-react-native) that wraps the native library for you, but this is not cross-platform

It seems like Apple does not support this out of the box the way android does, so you would have to go the route of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29422595/7819107), or a more robust library like [branch](https://branch.io/features/) which has a [react-native package](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/react-native) you can try out.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I managed to do it for Android with the mentioned getinstallreferer method. Regarding iOS I am trying right now with Firebase and Dynamic Links. Will update as soon as I have a solution. Dynamic Links are supported by react native firebase library

Answer (score 0):

If by `application id`, you're referring to `package name`, you can use the method `Context::getPackageName`
Check out this [Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getPackageName())

For example you can start an `activity` with the taken the `package name`:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=package_name"
```

That is the more elegant way. I think your question is answered by now. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks for replying but this is not exactly what I need.